# Using Zeppelin API: How do we import a new notebook from an json file stored on s3?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

According to the API documentation, it's possible to create a new Zeppeling note. https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#import-a-note
The question is, we already have a json file on S3 containing the notebook code. How we can refer it in the command line interface.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solve my question by using -d @'filename' parameter in curl command.  This is my solution:

http://[zeppelin-server]:[zeppelin-port]/api/notebook/import -d @'filenamenotebook.json'

Regards